# iterating in a dictionary.. (double iteration) python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary

```
example: A = {1:'one',2:'two' , 3: 'three}
```

so what I want is basically like a 2 for loops sort of stuff..
so that I can get the following order..

```
# 1 2
# 1 3
# 2 3
... and so on if more elements are there
```

so basically that o(n2) operation.. where we have a loop withing a loop
how do we achieve this in python dictionary.
I am having a hard time figuring that out..

```
for key in A.keys():
      # how do i Access all the other keys.. 
           # do something
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> A = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3: 'three'}
>>> list(it.combinations(A.keys(), 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: I was just lurking and I saw this and I just wanted to quote the docs for iterator.combinations()... "Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order." so OP should take care to make sure that his input is in the order he wants.

Comment: Right. I would also add that if the order is the one used in the examples, the OP should pay attention to sort the `A.keys()` rather than the outputted list: they will generate the same order, but the first call will have to sort far less elements than the latter.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but he could do `list(it.combinations(A.keys().sort(), 2))` right?

Comment: Nope. He should use `sorted(A.keys())` as `.sort()` is in place, so the expression would evaluate to `...nations(None, 2)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3], 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate over all pairs of keys, you can do it with simple for loops:

```
>>> d={1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}
>>> for (x,y) in ((x,y) for x in d for y in d if x!=y):
...     print x,y
```

Edit:

To avoid listing the same pair twice you can use a set to store the pairs before you iterate:

```
>>> for (x,y) in set(((min(x,y),max(x,y)) for x in d for y in d if x!=y)):
...     print x,y
```

But this is getting a bit unwieldy, I would suggest using `itertools.combinations` as shown in dstromberg's answer.

Comment: HI.. this works.. but can if there is 1 2 then i dont want 2 1 so basically whatever has been iterated in x should be excluded in y.. how do i do that